# Multiple ips in one line in iptables

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

I need to list all 192.168.1.X ips in one line. Will 192.168.1.* work?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -s 192.168.0.*/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Is what im wondering. This is not a router but rather a computer (Debian Jessie, x64)

Comment: Did you want "192.168.1.x" as in your text, or "192.168.0.x" as in your code snippet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats what the `/24` is, it marks the [CIDR block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks).

To allow all IPs for 192.168.1.*, you would use

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

Where as a single IP would be

```
192.168.1.123/32
```